# Cygwin: ssh-host-config fails with 'local group does not exist'

Tags: ssh, cygwin, hbase

I am trying to install Hbase on a VM under Windows 7.

I followed the instructions and everything is OK until i do the `ssh-host-config`.

I see the following:

```
>Should privilege separation be used? Yes
>new local account ‘sshd’? Yes
>Do you want to install sshd as a service? Yes
>Enter the value of CYGWIN for the daemon?[] just <enter>
>Do you want to use a different name? No
>create new privileged user account ‘cyg_server’ account? Yes
>Please enter the password: 
>Reenter: 

>User has been created
>System error 1376 has occurred
>The specified local group does not exist.
>Adding user cyg_server to local group root failed
>Please add cyg_server to local group before
```

Comment: What instructions did you follow? Cygwin has a bad record for never properly testing their own installation scripts before releasing new updates.

Comment: PS. You should probably change the title to include `Cygwin` in it, as "Hbase" is irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check what that lame error means, with:

```
$ NET HELPMSG 1376

The specified local group does not exist.
```

The problem seem to be that the script is not giving the new user account "Administrator" group membership. You can check this with: `net user cyg_server` from a normal windows command shell (CMD). Make sure the line reads:

```
Local Group Memberships  *Administrators  *Users
```

If it doesn't, you need to open the Windows control panel and navigate to User Accounts.
There you will find a new account called "Privileged server", which is the `cyg_server` account. You need to change the account type of that from `Standard` to `Administrator`.

Now restart `sshd` and check that it's running with:

```
$ cygrunsrv.exe --query sshd

Service             : sshd
Display name        : CYGWIN sshd
Current State       : Running
Controls Accepted   : Stop
Command             : /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

However, this is probably not the end of the story as these accounts cannot be used to login with, if they do not have a password assigned. You need to create (and add to /etc/passwd) a new account with remote login rights. And don't forget to check account password expiration...

Comment: For more related info, see my [other post here](http://serverfault.com/questions/579630/why-does-ssh-host-config-create-two-users-in-cygwin-on-windows-8-1/638438#638438).